# Equivalent code of __getitem__ in __iter__

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am trying to understand more about `__iter__` in Python 3. For some reason `__getitem__` is better understood by me than `__iter__`. I think I get somehow don't get the corresponding **next** implemention followed with `__iter__`.

I have this following code:

```
class Item:
    def __getitem__(self,pos):
        return range(0,30,10)[pos]

item1= Item()
print (f[1]) # 10
for i in item1:
   print (i) # 0 10 20
```

I understand the code above, but then again how do i write the equivalent code using `__iter__` and `__next__()` ?

```
class Item:
   def __iter__(self):
      return self
      #Lost here
   def __next__(self,pos):
      #Lost here
```

I understand when python sees a `__getitem__` method, it tries iterating over that object by calling the method with the integer index starting with `0`.

Comment: Try it on a real list. The `mylist.__iter__` function returns a generator. You can take some amount of steps through this generator by calling `my_generator.next()` some amount of times. However I wouldn't call it equivalent since list item access is constant time, while iterating until a certain point is linear time.

Comment: What about `def __iter__(self): return (x for x in range(0,30,10))`?

Comment: @machineyearning I need to pass an index too. (self,pos)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: In the code above, i actually wanted to pass an index argument too. For eg. if i wanted to achieve something like print (f[1]), 1 is the index i wanted to pass to the method.

Comment: The` __iter__` method does not take any arguments afaik. That's what `__getitem__` is for, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is clear to me now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a really good approach is to make `__iter__` a generator by `yield`ing values. This might be *less* intuitive but it is straight-forward; you just yield back the results you want and `__next__` is then provided automatically for you:

```
class Item:
   def __iter__(self):
      for item in range(0, 30, 10):
          yield item
```

This just uses the power of `yield` to get the desired effect, when `Python` calls `__iter__` on your object, it expects back an `iterator` (i.e an object that supports `__next__` calls), a generator does just that, producing each item as defined in your generator function (i.e `__iter__` in this case) when `__next__` is called:

```
>>> i = iter(Item())    
>>> print(i)  # generator, supports __next__
<generator object __iter__ at 0x7f6aeaf9e6d0>
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
10
>>> next(i)
20
```

Now you get the same effect as `__getitem__`. The difference is that no `index` is passed in, you have to manually loop through it in order to yield the result:

```
>>> for i in Item():
...    print(i)    
0
10
20
```

Apart from this, there's two other alternatives for creating an object that supports Iteration.

**One time looping: Make item an iterator**

Make `Item` an iterator by defining `__next__` and returning `self` from `__iter__` in this case, since you're not using `yield` the `__iter__` method returns `self` and `__next__` handles the logic of returning values:

```
class Item:

   def __init__(self):
      self.val = 0

   def __iter__(self):
      return self

   def __next__(self):
      if self.val > 2: raise StopIteration
      res = range(0, 30, 10)[self.val]
      self.val += 1
      return res
```

This also uses an auxiliary `val` to get the result from the range and check if we should still be iterating (if not, we raise `StopIteration`):

```
>>> for i in Item():
...    print(i)
0
10
20
```

The problem with this approach is that it is a one time ride, after iterating once, the `self.val` points to `3` and iteration can't be performed again. (using `yield` resolves this issue). (Yes, you could go and set `val` to 0 but that's just being sneaky.)

**Many times looping: create custom iterator object.**

The second approach is to use a custom iterator object specifically for your `Item` class and return it from `Item.__iter__` instead of `self`:

```
class Item:
    def __iter__(self):
        return IterItem()


class IterItem:
   def __init__(self):
      self.val = 0
   def __iter__(self):
      return self
   def __next__(self):
      if self.val > 2: raise StopIteration
      res = range(0, 30, 10)[self.val]
      self.val += 1
      return res
```

Now every time you iterate a new custom iterator is supplied and you can support multiple iterations over `Item` objects.

Comment: I like your comprehensive answer, and your smoking skeleton avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Iter returns a iterator, mainly a generator as @machineyearning told at the comments, with next you can iterate over the object, see the example:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elems   = range(10)
        self.current = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return (x for x in self.elems)

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current >= len(self.elems):
            self.current = 0
            raise StopIteration
        return self.elems[self.current]

>>> i = Item()
>>> a = iter(i)
>>> for x in a:
...     print x
...     
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> for x in i:
...     print x
...     
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: It's not appropriate to have a `__next__` method if your `__iter__` method returns something other than `self`. Having both a generator based `__iter__` and a `__next__` says that you're not sure if you're supposed to be an iterator or not.